# How can I sum and average my array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, input, average

I want to sum and average my array in Java. How can I do that?

```java
public class EjerciciosArrays extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayHtmlyCSS;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayCplusplus;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayJava;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayPython;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayJavaScript;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayPhp;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayMongoDB;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayMysql;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayAngularJS;
    ArrayList<Double> mi_arrayExpressJS;
    
    private void btnHtmlyCSSActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    
     mi_arrayHtmlyCSS  = new ArrayList<>(); //
          
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                mi_arrayHtmlyCSS.add(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese EVA "+(i)))); // 
                   }
           mi_arrayHtmlyCSS.forEach((a)-> {
            this.txtHtmlyCSS.append(a+"\n");
           });
           
        }   
    
        
            
           mi_arrayHtmlyCSS.forEach((a)-> {
            this.txtHtmlyCSS.append(a+"\n");
           });
           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand clearly what's you piece of code is for, but I'm gonna try to help you.
If you want to calculate the sum of elements in ArrayList you could do it like that

```
public double sum(List<Double> list) {


    double sum=0d;
    for(Double value:list) {
        sum+=value;
    }
    return sum;

}
```

In order to calculate the average you just have to divide the sum by the size of an array.

```
double sum=sum(mi_arrayHtmlyCSS);
double avg=sum/mi_arrayHtmlyCSS.size();
```

I didn't check nullable and divide by zero for simplicity.

Comment: Yes of course but Nekosor were already using Double so to keep it simple I also use it. But at this level I don't think it matters. I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i'm learning for program.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple programme to get sum and average of array in java. In this, the programme take the size of array and elements in array from userside.

```
    package practiceCode;
    import java.util.*;
    public class HandOnAverageCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Size:");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int[] nums = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter the integers:");
    
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Array is = ");
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.print( nums[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of elements in array = "+ sum);
    
    // to get the Average of array
    double avg = sum/size;
    System.out.println("Average value of array is : " + avg);
    sc.close();
    }

}
```